# Issues in High Order Component files after ejecting from Create React App

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I was using CRA 2.0, and wanted to eject so that I can manipulate the configurations. After ejecting, I am stuck with an issue where I get the compilation error:

```
./src/web-app-commons/HOC/OverlayWrapper.jsx
SyntaxError: /Users/prabhjotrai/temp/client-web/src/web-app-commons/HOC/OverlayWrapper.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (33:22):

  31 | export default WrappedComponent => {
  32 |   return class extends Component {
> 33 |     static propTypes = {
     |                      ^
  34 |       overlayProps: PropTypes.shape({
  35 |         open: PropTypes.bool
  36 |       })

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I have tried everything related to adding this plugin(including adding `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` as dev dependency and referencing it in babel configuration), and I presume that it's related to https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8648. But when I remove this specific file, the next error I get is:

```
./src/web-app-commons/HOC/Preview.jsx
SyntaxError: /Users/prabhjotrai/temp/client-web/src/web-app-commons/HOC/Preview.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'objectRestSpread' isn't currently enabled (60:3):

  58 |   persistent = true,
  59 |   overflowX = 'inherit',
> 60 |   ...props
     |   ^
  61 | } = {}) => WrappedComponent => {
  62 |   return class extends Component {
  63 |     displayName = `${WrappedComponent.displayName ||

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread (https://git.io/vb4Ss) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

My gut feeling says that it's something related to High Ordered Components, since I am not getting this "spread" error or class properties declaration error anywhere else in the code. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Here are my babel dependencies:

```
~/temp/client-web   master ●  cat package.json | grep babel
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^9.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^5.0.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-glamorous-to-emotion": "^1.0.1",
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "babel": {
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added a babelrc file (removing the configuration from package.json), with the following details but had no luck:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "react-app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is still a proposal, so it is not available by default in Babel.

Just add @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread to the plugins like they said

Comment: @PrabhjotRai I referenced second error, but both errors are the same. Both things are still in proposal which means they aren't part of the Babel by default and you need to use those plugins

Comment: I tried adding them by creating a babelrc file. Let me edit the post to add that as well.